# Cannot correctly trim and bold matching words from two strings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a `SearchBar` in my application which offers suggestions starting with the input from that `SearchBar`.

For example: Typing `skrillex` in the SearchBar will result in the following suggestions:

```
skrillex
skrillex kyoto
skrillex cinema
skrillex bangarang
skrillex live
```

I am trying to **bold** the words in the suggestions which match the input from the SearchBar.

For the same example above, the result would be:

```
<b>skrillex</b>
<b>skrillex</b> kyoto
<b>skrillex</b> cinema
<b>skrillex</b> bangarang
<b>skrillex</b> live
```

The code I am currently using is the following:

```
item.startsWith(this.state.searchText.trim()) ?
                        [<Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>{this.state.searchText.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ')}</Text>,
                        <Text>{item.slice((this.state.searchText.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ').length)).replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ')}</Text>]
                        : (<Text>{item}</Text>)
```

This works for most cases, but there are some edge cases in which the code above incorrectly outputs a suggestion. For example, typing `skrillex.`(with a space after the dot) outputs the following suggestions:

```
skrillex. cinema 
skrillex.bangarang
skrillex. live 
skrillex. songs 
skrillex.com
```

After running my code from above to bold out the matching words, this is what the output is:

```
<b>skrillex.</b> cinema 
<b>skrillex.</b>angarang
<b>skrillex.</b> live 
<b>skrillex.</b> songs
<b>skrillex.</b>om
```

Basically, the `.slice` has cut the `b` from `bangarang` (`skrillex.bangarang`) and `c` from `com` (`skrillex.com`).

Can anyone spot where the error is? I am also open to any alternative ways for doing this since I believe mine is not that efficient.

Comment: use can give a try to https://github.com/clauderic/react-native-highlight-words

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is this expression: `/\s\s+/g, ' '`. You are replacing whitespaces with a whitespace.

If you try this on Chrome console: `'skrillex. '.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ').length`, you'll see that the length is 10 and in the case of *skrillex.com* and *skrillex.bangarang* the characters at the 10th position are **o** and **a** respectively.